# Bash - Get the entire file name having space in it

Tags: bash

I have a folder in which there are a few files:

```
a b.jpg
c d.jpg
```

basically, I want to list the files and carry out some operations on them, however I failed to do by:

`for i in $( ls $folder ); do echo $i; done`

each line of output is a part of a file name rather than the entire one:

```
a
b.jpg
c
d.jpg
```

How can I avoid this in Bash,

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in $folder/*; do echo "$i"; done
```

or:

```
( cd $folder; for i in *; do echo "$i"; done )
```

Comment: +1 This is the better way to do it -- using a shell wildcard directly is much more reliable than trying to parse ls's output. Also, note the double-quotes around `$i` -- they're important when working with filenames with spaces or other funny characters.

Comment: Be aware that the first usage with "$folder" gives the filename prefixed with the $folder, and the second is a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but this is how I usually do it:

```
ls $folder | while read filename; do
  echo $filename
done
```

Comment: It works, thanks. however, can you explain how it works please? also, at last of the output, it prints out "exit 1", at least in zsh.